# Get value from input component and use it in another component in React

Tags: reactjs

I'm new to React and have this simple code example where I simply need to take value from input and show the value back.

```js
    class App extends React.Component {

      constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.state = { word : ""};
        this.onClick = this.onClick.bind(this);
      }

      onClick(e){
        this.setState({word : /* how to obtain input value?? */});
      }

      render() {
        return (
          <>
            <form>
                <input type="text"/>
                <button onClick={this.onClick}>Say it!</button>
            </form>
            <div>
              {this.state.word}
            </div>
          </>
        );
      }
    }
```

I know react want's me to use component state as a way to propagate information from parent component to it's children. What I don't know is how I should *obtain state of a children to be used in another children*.

I believe this should be doable in react in simple manner as the equivalent way of doing it using pure DOM or JQuery would also be very simple (one or two lines of code).

Comment: @jonrsharpe Could you put this as answer and show code sample? I think already use state on the parent there in my code example

Comment: Read https://reactjs.org/docs/forms.html

Answer (score 1):

You can use `createRef`

```
import React, { createRef } from "react";
import "./styles.css";

class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { word: "" };
    this.onClick = this.onClick.bind(this);
  }
  textInput = createRef();
  onClick(e) {
    this.setState({ word: this.textInput.current.value });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <form>
          <input ref={this.textInput} type="text" />
          <button onClick={this.onClick} type="button">
            Say it!
          </button>
        </form>
        <div>{this.state.word}</div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
export default App;
```

check here [CodeSandBox](https://codesandbox.io/s/dazzling-franklin-xodw8)

Comment: Thanks. This is workable and at least now I know what to google. Question: If I have more than one <input> does this mean I must have one refs assigned to each? Is this...proper way of doing this or just a workaround? I really am in uncharted waters with react.

Comment: so you can set state in parent component and share it  for your both children component, you can see in here [codeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/dazzling-franklin-xodw8)

Answer (score 0):

A few things here. First I don't see children as you mention. Moreover, you say `obtain state of a children to be used in another children`. You have just one parent component here. Then, you are using a `<form>` which means a button inside will `submit` the values so you need the escape hatch of `e.preventDefault()`. Finally, if you must use a class based component instead of functional component, you don't need any more `constructor` and you can bind your functions with an arrow function. Here is a working example of what I presume you are asking: https://codesandbox.io/s/sleepy-minsky-giyhk